# textbox.focus does not work. vb

Tags: vb.net

i have a problem with command textbox.focus it does not work "when I entered the key it goes to under line inside the textbox so i can not make another command because there is a one space or the navigation arrow still in the second row inside the textbox"...
this is my code

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

when i use this code

```
 If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        msgbox("any thing")
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End If
```

it works good
any one help me please?
thanks

Comment: If you are processing the KeyDown event, that control already has the focus

Comment: The reason it works with the messagebox is because the textbox loses focus and the messagebox gains it.

Comment: MessageBoxes don't always make good debugging tools.  They can interfere with the process.

Comment: LarsTech is right, you should Debug.Write or Console.Write or use breakpoints (..which can also be painful in certain circumstances) instead.

Comment: Apart from anything else, the MSDN documentation clearly states that an application programmer should not be calling `Focus` anyway, but rather `Select`.

Comment: It is NEVER enough to simply say "it doesn't work".  You ALWAYS need to explain exactly how what actually happens differs from what you expect.  As @Plutonix says, the `TextBox` you're trying to focus already has focus so obviously what you are expecting is not connected to reality.  We can't read your mind.

Comment: @jmcilhinney "when I entered the key it goes to under line inside the textbox so i can not make another command because there is a one space or the navigation arrow still in the second row inside the textbox"

Comment: Why are you using a multi-line `TextBox` in the first place if you don't want multiple lines?

Comment: @jmcilhinney it is the same thing just i want to get you the problem. meaning that if keep it one line the same thing you have to press Backspace key to accept any other command.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
     TextBox1.Text = ""
     SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}")
     TextBox1.Focus()
End If
```

End Sub